# Limit with e number, explain me this...

Tags: limits

[image]

Please explain me how somebody got this, step by step what's done here...

Comment: It's wrong. The middle term ought to be $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \ln \left(1+x\right)^{1/x}$.

Comment: OK, thanks for that, but even if it was 1/x, how did somebody get that out of $\dfrac{ln(1+x)}{x}$?

Comment: You have $\ln (y^a) = a\ln y$, so $\frac1x\ln (1+x) = \ln \left((1+x)^{1/x}\right)$.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot, I appreciate it :D

Comment: @DanielFischer I'd like you to post the answer, cause you helped me most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a mistake: it is $\displaystyle \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = \log(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

So, remembering that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{x}=e$ and putting $1/t = x$...